# Is there a way to force-fit your div content to a single paper (letter) when printing/saving to pdf from Chrome?

Tags: jquery, css, google-chrome

I'm trying to fit a view to a single page whenever I want to print/save to pdf the said view. The view includes a dynamic table where the contents are unpredictable. My problem is that whenever the table is too long, the latter part of the view gets cut and gets continued on the next page. I'm only adjusting the view via zoom on my CSS for print. My zoom is currently set at 66% and it's hard to find the sweet spot since the number of the table rows are unpredictable. Is this something that is not possible at all?

Attaching a screenshot for reference:

[image]

Comment: I think zoom only works in IE

Comment: It works on Chrome too. The display is larger than that without the zoom.

Answer (score 0):

A sweet spot, perhaps not.

Tables can be pretty nasty in prints.

Assuming that each table is inside a table-container with a limited size of sorts.

Styles:

```
<style type='text/css'>
    .table-container {
        width: 700px;
        overflow: scroll;
    }

    table {
        width: 100;
    }
</style>
```

HTML:

```
<div class="table-container">
    <table>
    ...
    </table>
</div>
```

Script:

First adding an extension to JQuery at the top of our script:

```
jQuery.fn.hasHScrollBar = function () {
   return this.get(0).scrollWidth > this.innerWidth();
}
```

Then loop through until we either hit the minimum font-size of totally unreadable or the scrollBar disappear, whichever comes first.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.table-container').each(function() {
        var font_size = 24;
        var min_font_size = 5;
        while ($(this).hasHScrollBar()) {
            if (font_size < min_font_size)
                return false;
            $('table').css("font-size", font_size + "px");
            font_size--;
        }
        $(this).css("overflow", "hidden");
    });
});
```

Or as a button:

```
$("#print-button").click(function () {
    $('.table-container').each(function() {
        var font_size = 24;
        var min_font_size = 5;
        while ($(this).hasHScrollBar()) {
            if (font_size < min_font_size)
                return false;
            $('table').css("font-size", font_size + "px");
            font_size--;
        }
        $(this).css("overflow", "hidden");
    });
    window.print();
});
```

-- update --

Or the whole thing with Scaling:

```
body {
    width: 700px;
    overflow: scroll;
}

.page {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Assuming you have a top class element called Page that wraps the whole thing. Since scaling fixates itself on the center of the element some extra adjustments are needed like setting the left-margin. It works in the latest versions of Chrome, Opera, IE, and Firefox.

```
$("body").each(function () {
    var innerPage = $(this).find(".page");
    var BaseWidth = parseInt($(innerPage).css("width"));
    var CalcWidth = BaseWidth;
    var scale = 1.0;
    var min_scale = 0.2;
    while ($(this).hasHScrollBar()) {
        if (scale < min_scale)
            break;
        CalcWidth = parseInt(BaseWidth * scale);
        $(innerPage).css("transform", "scale(" + scale + ")");
        $(innerPage).css('margin-left', (-1 * ((BaseWidth - CalcWidth)/2)));
        scale -= 0.1;
    }
    $(this).css("overflow", "hidden");
});
```

Comment: Should this really be on document ready? What if I only want it to apply when the user clicks the print button?

Comment: Scratch that, I was able to make it work but it still won't fit since it's only adjusting the font size of the tables. is there a way to scale the whole div?

Comment: What's keeping it too big?